# Joomla изменения шаблона

Tags: joomla, шаблоны, denwer

У меня проблема с внесением изменений при редактировании шаблона joomla (yoo_master2_demo_package_j3.zip), т.е. при изменении стилей в текстовом редакторе с последующем сохранением, правки на шаблоне не вступаю в силу. Код файла изменяется и сохраняется в текстовом редакторе, а на шаблоне нет. Я и денвер перезапускал и текстовые редакторы менял (пробовал Sublime и PHPStorm). Если фаил CSS удалить то стили пропадают и на шаблоне, а вот правки не вносятся. Что делать?

Comment: Скорее всего, файл закешировался браузером, поэтому перезагрузка сервера не помогает. Откройте в другом браузере. и если увидите разницу, надо просто перезагрузить проблемный браузер со сбросом кеша. Чаще всего - CTRL+R

Comment: Помогло. В опере все открылось с изменениями. Огромное спасибо!!! Золотой вы человек :)